# Links from HTML are going to root instead of the same folder? (LocalHost)

Tags: html, relative-path

```
// THIS WORKS ('contact' is the folder we're in)
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../contact/local.css">

// THESE DO NOT WORK (they point to a 'local.css' in the root directory)
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./local.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="local.css">
```

This is only an issue on 'localhost'. It works perfectly well on the web-server I'm using but for testing it would be nice if I can use './'.

I'm using *Phpstorm* with *PHP Built-in Web Server*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66191) for PHP Built-in Webserver.
Currently, the webserver processes the path without trailing `/` as a file even if it's a directory.

To fix this, please make sure you have a trailing forward slash in your URL.

E.g. Instead of http://localhost/folder, use http://localhost/folder/

Comment: That's such a weird fix, but it works perfectly now... many thanks.